# How to run a program on a remote PC via command line?

Tags: windows, remote

How can I run a program on a remote Windows PC in our network without the need of killing an existing remote-desktop-connection? I only need a command line for running the program and getting its results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

This is what you'd do to execute a CLI program on a remote computer using PsExec:

```
psexec \\REMOTECOMPUTER "path_to_program_executable"
```

You can learn more about PsExec and its various options along with some examples [here](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)

Comment: How can I run something on Google VM (Windows)? But I mean that it will launch a GUI. Namely if I log on (RDP) I will see the program running on the desktop.

Comment: @Royi try `psexec -i -d -s \\remotecomputer command`. Please read the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec#using-psexec) as well if you run into issues.

Comment: Can `\\remotecomputer` be an IP?

Comment: @Royi Yes, \\ipaddress

Answer (score 1):

On more option is the built in [winrs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/winrs)

```
winrs.exe -r:<RemoteComputerName> <TheCommandToRun>
winrs.exe -r:MyRemoteServer ipconfig
```

**winrs vs. psexec**

**advantages winrs**

- Built in, no download needed
- Faster and more reliable than psexec

**advantages psexec**

- Works with IP (winrs needs the computername (NetBIOS name) of the machine)
- Can run processes in system-context