# Is it possible to trigger a scanner from a remote computer?

Tags: windows, batch, printer, shortcuts, remote

Is there any method of triggering a scan command from Windows Scan and Fax from a remote computer either using PowerShell, a batch file or even possibly a shortcut?

Comment: Any printer I have used does not have remote access software, so there is probably not a way for a printer at A to scan something on B.

Comment: What is the printer model? If the printer comes with a scanning app, you may be able to start it with the method here: https://superuser.com/questions/734642/how-to-run-a-program-on-a-remote-pc-via-command-line

Comment: This question needs more details about what you are trying to do. First, how is connected the scanner: network scanner or attached to a PC?